# requiring a dependency of a linked npm module does not work?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

My local module A links to local module B with `npm link`.
And module B has react as a dependency.
When module A requires react, the module is not found.

If this regarded 'normal' packages (without npm link) module A would get react under `node_modules` when it installs module B.

Is there any way to be able to require react from module A when using `npm link` without manually listing it as a dependency?

Comment: Are you saying that you are wanting to use `react` in module `A` without explicitly declaring it as a dependency?

Comment: yes, which would be the case if module `B` would be a normal published module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Longer Answer:** `npm link` just creates a symlink in `node_modules` of module A to module B via the global folder. It does not provide any dependency resolution/installation/flattening like `npm install` would. This is useful for example if you are developing on module A and B simultaneously; changes to installed packages in module B don't necessitate re-resolving/installing/flattening of the package tree in A.

You can potentially mess with your `NODE_PATH` environment variable to specify module B's `node_modules` as a source for your `require`s when running A and effectively use the dependencies of B in A.

However, please rethink why you want to create an invisible dependency like this. You are choosing to break encapsulation of the modules. If module A needs `react`, A needs to specify that in the package.json. When you later decide to use module A for some other project that doesn't include B, there's no problem. When you decide to scuttle `react` from module B, you don't break A.